# Dynamically get type of object property

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the type of an object property using a variable? I.e. using the string `x`, I would like to get `string` type and using the string `y` I want to get `number` type.

```
type Obj = Readonly<{
  x: string,
  y: number
}>

const obj = {
  x: 'abc',
  y: 123
}

type TypeOfX = Obj['x']; // this works fine and returns string
type TypeOfY = Obj['y']; // this works fine and returns number

type Property = keyof Obj;
const property: Property = 'x';
// error here
type TypeOfObjProperty = Obj[property];
```

The errors are:

```
Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)
'property' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof property'?(2749)
Exported type alias 'TypeOfObjProperty' has or is using private name 'property'.(4081)
```

Comment: You can't use runtime information (the value of `property`) to define a compile-time construct (a type). You *could* do `const property = "x";` and then `Obj[typeof property]`, because `typeof property` would be the string literal type `"x"`. But you can't do it with the *value* of the variable, just its type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if `property` is of type `keyof Obj` and `Obj` is readonly, isn't it known at compile time that the value can only be `x` or `y`?

Comment: If you do `type TypeOfObjProperty = Obj[typeof property];` it will correctly infer the type as `string` or `number` depending on the `property` variable. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. As the error message says, if you use `typeof property` with this specific example, [it'll work](https://tsplay.dev/w6Bprw) (because TypeScript's flow analysis tells it that `property` is of type `"x"`). If TS couldn't determine that from flow analysis, the type you'd get would be `string | number` because the type of `property` is `"x" | "y"` ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPjgeN)). But `Obj[property]` is using `property` as a value, not as a type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, now I understand the question. Thanks!

Comment: I think I understand now - typescript knows that `property` will be `x | y` at compile time. So it can verify that it's a valid object key, but not which valid key it will be and therefore what the type of the key's value will be.

Comment: I think my only option is to have explicit logic for each key like `if (key === 'a' || key === 'b') {`, rather than working out the type of the key which typescript can't know because it's not there at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

While `Obj[property]` only works as a type when `property` is a type, you can use generics and `extends` to simulate this, at least on the function level:

```
type Obj = Readonly<{
  x: string,
  y: number
}>

function f<Property extends keyof Obj, TypeOfObjProperty extends Obj[Property]>
  (prop: Property, value: TypeOfObjProperty) {
    // TypeOfObjProperty is the type Obj[prop]
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigJQgQwCYHsB2ANiADwDeAUFFAB4BcUAzsAE4CW+A5gDRVQgN8AVwC2cCCwoBfAHwUKAMyH4AxsDYEoCkgAUWuSC1BQINYBHzZGUANYQQuBbETcoAFXAQYC+Aj0GJY1NzS2tfAG1-Q1AAXTlqAAowfTAGKMCQVwA3TEIhCAYPSG9fdKMQAEooSmpqAHo6qAA6FukgA)

Depending on what you're doing, this may give you the type `TypeOfObjProperty` that you need.